# Algorithm to simplify a Polygon/Series of Points to a given number of Points

Tags: polygon, point, line, algorithm, simplify

I have a polygon (or let's call it just a series of points). I want to simplify it (reduce the amount of points) to a given number of points.

Currently I use Douglas Peucker and try to guess the correct epsilon. That works more or less (I get approximately the given amount of points). The biggest problem is, that I have to call DP over and over again. Since I want to massively reduce the points, e.G. from 10.000s to 30 the process is a bit frustrating.

So I thought, that I might create my own version of DP, were I stop when I reach the amount of points I am looking for. Are there any existing or maybe better solutions available?

Comment: approximately how many points would you want to reach at the end of the process ? Are you still far from the extent rectangle of your polygon.

Comment: Visvalingam's algorithm suits probably better for your use case. An interactive example is at https://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/

Comment: @radouxju Well I reach the desired amount of points. But I have to rerun DP quite often. Therefore, I am looking for a better solution, since I want to calculate the simplification more or less efficient.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks yes, you might be right. Adapting the Visvalingam to stop when a given node count is reached would be easier.

Comment: That simplify is huge... you may want to use a topological simplification with postgis topology for example.... https://strk.kbt.io/blog/2012/04/13/simplifying-a-map-layer-using-postgis-topology/